# How to check if the scanned QRCode contains anything but numbers

Tags: ios, swift, metadata, qr-code, barcode-scanner

For my project I am using a QRCodescanner which should only respond to the qrcode  if the code only just contains numbers. So anytime the Code contains anything but a number it should give an error alert.

Right now every time I scan a code which does not contain only an integer the app crashes.

Here is how I am handling the output so far:

```
 func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
    
    
    if metadataObjects.count != 0 {
        
        if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject{
            
            if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr{
                self.session.stopRunning()
                
                ergebnis = Int(object.stringValue!)!
                
                barnummer = ergebnis/1000*1000
                
                qrbar = [QRBereich]()
                qrbarname = ""
                
                fetchData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Before converting the object Value into a Int variable I want to check if it really just contains numbers, but I have no idea how to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to safely unwrap optionals. Your app crashes because you are misusing the `!` operator.

```
if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr{
    self.session.stopRunning()

    if let string = object.stringValue {
        if let ergebnis = Int(string) {
            barnummer = ergebnis/1000*1000

            qrbar = [QRBereich]()
            qrbarname = ""

            fetchData()
        } else {
            // Not an integer, show error
        }
    }
}
```